# Sum Records Based on Date Falling Within a Range from a Lookup Table - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sum, date-range

My intentions are to have a query sum records based on the date ranges that their occur date falls within. The date ranges are created via the below table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DateRanges') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DateRanges
Create Table #DateRanges
 (Start_num int, End_Num int, Day_Period varchar(10), Day_Bin varchar(8))

 Insert Into #DateRanges
 Values (0,-6,'7Day', 'Current'),
        (-7,-13,'7Day','1'),
        (-14,-20,'7Day','2'),
        (-21,-27,'7Day','3'),
        (-28,-34,'7Day','4'),
        (0,-27,'28Day','Current'),
        (-28,-55,'28Day','1'),
        (-56,-83,'28Day','2'),
        (-84,-111,'28Day','3'),
        (-112,-139,'28Day','4'),
        (0,-83,'84Day','Current'),
        (-84,-167,'84Day','1'),
        (-168,-251,'84Day','2'),
        (-252,-335,'84Day','3'),
        (-336,-419,'84Day','4'),
        (0,-363,'364Day','Current'),
        (-364,-727,'364Day','1'),
        (-728,-1091,'364Day','2'),
        (-1092,-1455,'364Day','3'),
        (-1456,-1819,'364Day','4')
```

The following query is attempting to query my RMS and use the above table to sum records

```
select 
  'category' as n_Group, 
   ab2.ItemCategory as Item,
   DLU.Day_Period, 
   DLU.Day_Bin, 
   sum(g.occ_date Between DateAdd("d",DLU.end_num,@Date1) AND DateAdd   ("d",DLU.start_Num,@Date1)) as n_Count

FROM g_data g
     left join LUab ab2
        on g.ext= ab2.ext,
     #DateRanges DLU

Where g.occ_date Between DateAdd("d", -1819, @Date1) and  @Date1

Group By
    ab2.ItemCategory,
    DLU.Day_Period,
    DLU.Day_Bin
```

Another user assisted in the creation with the above query, but it was for MS Access. I have changed gears and am now attempting to do this part of the project in SQL Server and the following line is not compatible with SQL Server
 `sum(g.occ_date Between DateAdd("d",DLU.end_num,@Date1) AND DateAdd("d",DLU.start_Num,@Date1)) as n_Count` .

An incorrect syntax error is showing the the last parenthesis in the sum line. In my tinkering, I tried `Count(iif(g.occ_date Between DateAdd("d",DLU.end_num,@Date1) AND DateAdd("d",DLU.start_Num,@Date1)), g.rin) as n_Count` and the query ran, but returned `n_count` totals that appeared to possibly be counting the category in the entire rms. `Case When g.occ_date Between DateAdd("d",DLU.end_num,@Date1) AND DateAdd("d",DLU.start_Num,@Date1) then 1 else 0 End as n_Count` returned the same results at Count iif

Below is example data (sanitized) that resulted from the example query... My apologies for the formatting, searched the help sections and couldn't find a better method. ItemType and ItemDesc are subcategories and are going to be summed in the same manner as ItemCategory with union queries

`occ_date   ItemCategory    Itemetype   ItemDesc    randnum
11/10/2011  A   AS  AAS 1.01E-07
1/21/2015   V   VV  VVA 1.02E-07
3/6/2001    L   LP  LLP 3.85E-07
8/25/2017   L   LS  LLS 4.41E-07
12/7/2008   C   CC  CCC 5.62E-07
2/28/2009   V   VV  VVA 6.54E-07
6/24/2012   M   MM  MMM 6.76E-07
6/26/2006   A   AA  AAA 9.86E-07
3/1/1994    Q   QQ  QQP 1.11E-06
1/9/2018    M   MM  MMM 1.55E-06
11/6/1992   T   TA  TTA 2.00E-06
6/3/2009    V   VV  VVV 2.18E-06
10/26/1996  M   MM  MMM 2.28E-06
1/21/2017   M   MM  MMM 2.34E-06
3/28/2012   N   NN  NN  2.35E-06
5/1/1999    M   MM  MMM 2.52E-06
6/1/2014    S   SR  SSR 2.87E-06
10/2/2016   V   VV  VVV 2.91E-06
8/5/1988    C   CC  CCC 3.33E-06
4/6/2018    N   NN  NNN 3.34E-06`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the #DateRanges.  Please run the following and paste the resulting data file above.  This will give us some test data to work with for your solution.

```
Select TOP 20 *  From (
    Select Top 5000
       g.occ_date
      ,g.ext
      ,ab2.ItemCategory
      , RAND(convert(varbinary, newid())) as randnum
    FROM      g_data g
    left join LUab ab2
            on g.ext= ab2.ext
    order by randnum
    ) zz
```

> > later the same day...  try this.  I just changed SUM to COUNT(*), and moved the 'Between DLU ...' to become Where..AND...

```
select 
  'category' as n_Group, 
   ab2.ItemCategory as Item,
   DLU.Day_Period, 
   DLU.Day_Bin, 
   count(*)  as n_Count

FROM g_data g
     left join LUab ab2
        on g.ext= ab2.ext,
     #DateRanges DLU

Where g.occ_date Between DateAdd("d", -1819, @Date1) and  @Date1
and (g.occ_date Between DateAdd("d",DLU.end_num,@Date1) AND DateAdd   ("d",DLU.start_Num,@Date1))

Group By
    ab2.ItemCategory,
    DLU.Day_Period,
        DLU.Day_Bin
```

> > 3/14 13:45 Here are my results using @Date1 of  '3/1/2019'. 
> >     All the other date is too ancient.  What do you get?  What should the results look like?

```
n_Group Item    Day_Period  Day_Bin n_Count
category    L   364Day         1    1
category    M   364Day         1    1
category    M   364Day         2    1
category    M   84Day          4    1
category    N   364Day     Current  1
category    N   84Day          3    1
category    S   364Day         4    1
category    V   364Day         2    1
category    V   364Day         4    1
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @donPablo. The example data is pasted in my original question (probably not properly). I plugged your suggested edits in and the results were the same as what my trouble shooting attempts returned.